# laravel get latest 3 record from pivot table in eloquent way

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I've an items table and a suppliers table with many to many relationship.
the supplier will quote the price differently at different date.
How do I get the latest 3 pricing (regardless of supplier) for each item using eloquent?

items table

| id | item_code | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Code 1 | Item 1 |
| 2 | Code 2 | Item 2 |

suppliers table

| id | supplier_code | supplier_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier 1 | Name 1 |
| 2 | Supplier 2 | Name 2 |

item_supplier

| id | item_id | supplier_id | price | price_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 2022-12-01 00:11:22 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 101 | 2022-12-02 00:11:22 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 98 | 2022-12-03 00:11:22 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 95 | 2022-12-04 00:11:22 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 120 | 2022-12-05 00:11:22 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 105 | 2022-12-06 00:11:22 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | 100 | 2022-12-07 00:11:22 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | 101 | 2022-12-08 00:11:22 |
| 9 | 2 | 2 | 98 | 2022-12-09 00:11:22 |
| 10 | 2 | 2 | 95 | 2022-12-10 00:11:22 |
| 11 | 1 | 1 | 120 | 2022-12-11 00:11:22 |
| 12 | 1 | 2 | 105 | 2022-12-12 00:11:22 |

what I would like to get is like below

| item_name | supplier_name | price | price_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Name 2 | 120 | 2022-12-05 00:11:22 |
| Item 1 | Name 1 | 120 | 2022-12-11 00:11:22 |
| Item 1 | Name 2 | 105 | 2022-12-12 00:11:22 |
| Item 2 | Name 1 | 101 | 2022-12-08 00:11:22 |
| Item 2 | Name 2 | 98 | 2022-12-09 00:11:22 |
| Item 2 | Name 2 | 95 | 2022-12-10 00:11:22 |

```
class Item extends Model
{
public function supplier() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class)
        ->withPivot('price', 'price_at')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
public function item() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class)
        ->withPivot('price', 'price_at')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Tried below but I dont know how to limit it to 3 latest pricing for each item

```
Item::whereKey($this->selectedItems)
        ->with(['supplier' => function ($q) {
            $q->orderBy('price_at','DESC');
        }])
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#limit-and-offset) shows, you can use the `take` method to limit results to a specific number.

So we could do something like

```
Item::whereKey($this->selectedItems)
    ->with(['supplier' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('price_at','DESC');
    }])->take(3)->get();
```

Comment: this will limit the number of items being retrieved, not the record in the pivot.

Comment: You could alter the query to to limit the model within the relation when ordering. `Item::with(['supplier' => function($q) { $q->orderBy('price_at', 'DESC')->limit(3); }])->whereKey($this->selectedItems)->get();`

Comment: Tried, this limit the number of supplier being retrieved, not the record in the pivot